# Finding Tangents to a curve that pass through the origin

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the number of tangents to a curve that all pass through the origin.  The curve's equation is $y=x^3 + x^2 - 22x + 20$.  I also need to find the equation of said tangents.

Comment: I don't know where to start, I found the first derivative, knowing that it would be the same as the slope of the tangent at a specific point.  Only I don't know what that point is.

Answer (score 2):

The parametric form is $t,t^3+t^2-22t+20$

The gradient at $x=t$ will be $$3t^2+2t-22$$

So, the equation of the tangent at $x=t$ will be $$\frac{y-(t^3+t^2-22t+20)}{x-t}=3t^2+2t-22$$

This has to pass through the origin $(0,0)$

Hope you can take it home from here

Comment: Sadly I can't seem to take it from there, this is one of those questions where I need everything spelled out for me, sorry.  I've been trying to figure it out too long :p

Comment: I never really learned parametric equations or forms in math and now we've been this question so I'm a bit lost

Comment: @ZacharyHeuss, See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParametricEquations.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation

Comment: Thanks, I actually did solve it, just used the derivative as the slope (adds an x onto the last number) then set it equal to the derivative grouped common factors and then factored it to get (2, -12)

Comment: @ZacharyHeuss,Can you please share your steps?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use formula for tangent line:
$$y-y_0=y'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$
We know that $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Let's find $y'(x_0)$:
$y'(x_0)=3x_0^2+2x_0-22$ 

Plugin what we know:
$$-y_0=(3x_0^2+2x_0-22)*-x_0$$
We aslo know that $y_0=x_0^3+x_0^2-22x_0+20$
$$-x_0^3-x_0^2+22x_0-20=-3x_0^3-2x_0^2+22x_0$$
$$2x_0^3+x_0^2-20=0$$
Only real solution is 2. $x_0=2$ and $y_0=-12$.
Let tangent line be $y=kx+l$.
$k=y'(2)=-6$
$-12=-6*2+l\to l=0$
But we want l to be zero. 
Our solution is $y=-6x$.